# PySimpleGui ListBox where in values is selection?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

so, I have an application, written in python with pysimplegui. In here, I have a ListBox, which contains Event 's, which are stored in the list values. When I click an item in the list, how do I get the index of that item in values?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg


class Event(BaseModel):
    title: str
    moment: datetime
    description: str

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} at {str(self.moment)}"


values = [
    Event(title="test", moment=datetime(2023, 7, 2), description="hi"),
    Event(title="eger", moment=datetime(2023, 7, 4), description="34twerg"),
]


event_select_tab = [
    [sg.Text("event list editor")],
    [sg.Listbox(values, enable_events=True, key="-SELECT EVENT-", size=(25, 10))],
    [sg.Button("edit event", key="-EDIT EVENT-", enable_events=True)],
]

layout = [[sg.TabGroup([[sg.Tab("events", event_select_tab)]])]]

# Create the window
window = sg.Window("editor", layout)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or
    # presses the OK button
    if event == "OK" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    else:
        print(event, values)

window.close()
```

I already tried iterating through `values`, but this doesn't work when there are multiple items with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call following method of the Listbox instance, like `window["-SELECT EVENT-"].get_indexes()`

> get_indexes()
>
> Returns the items currently selected as a list of indexes